# Trying to update Manufacturer value but not working Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, products

I am trying to set or update `Manufacturer` value using code but its not working.Manufacturer is dropdrown on admin side.I am trying code like this :

```
$productcity = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $loadpro= $productcity->load($id);
       $loadpro->setManufacturer($wholedata['manufacture']);
        $loadpro->save();
```

What am i doing wrong ? thanks
I am adding screenshot for attribute.May be it help
[image]
[image]

Comment: $wholedata['manufacture'] contains id or value (text) ?

Comment: it is `id` like `117`.

Comment: check my question.I added screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- attribute is of type int or varchar
- attribute is in same attribute set as the product
- attribute is allowed for the product type `apply_to`
- attribute should be loaded with the product, is this the case?
- don't save the product in `frontend`, this is not possible, because `orig_data` are not set

Comment: I have added Screenshot of my attribute .May be it help to understand.

Comment: Did you check the points? Is your product a simple item?

Comment: Yes my product is simple product.

Comment: Is the attribute set on the product? If the attribute is set before the save, I think it is time for xdebug to dig down into the saving process...

Comment: Yes it is set on the product.I used it and it was working perfect.After changing code on front and trying to update Manufacturer it stop updating.When i print the values it gives me `0` for Manufacturer.